# Is this information authentic?

Tags: hadith, history, authenticity, isnad

I came across a certain information regarding the aftermath about the battle against a tribe called Banu Hawazin and that is,

"Muhammad(pbuh) gave a girl called Zaynab bint Hayyan to Uthman ibn Affan(R.A). Uthman(R.A) had sexual intercourse with her and she detested him."

The source of this information is Al-waqidi's kitab al-maghazi(Rizwi Faizer's version) page no. 462
https://books.google.com/books?id=gZknAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA462

I know that Al-waqidi is rejected by Hadith scholars but what I want to know is that, is Al-Waqidi the sole source of this information or did anyone else narrate it through authentic chain of transmitters?

Comment: Al-Waqidi's book can hardly be referred to as a hadith book.

Comment: I know that is a book of campaigns and biography and I did not mean to make it sound like that book has any authority just that al-waqidi is the source of many fabricated stories and is this story about Uthman(R.A)one of them that's what I wanted to know.Cause this particular information is used by some people for nefarious purposes.

Comment: Well it is a fact that our prophet gave his Sahabah several female slaves from the prisoners of war from Hawazin among them Zaynab bint Hayyan some corrected her name to Zaynab bint Khanaas. The addition that she detested him is neither mentioned in  Sirat ibn Hisham nor in Usd al-Ghbah of ibn Atheer. It was rather the case that she loved somebody else -her paternal cousin- and was either married to him -the wording may allow this interpretation- or promised for marriage to him -which seems more correct- and Allah knows best. Ibn Ishaaq reports actually that 'Uthman and all others freed them.

Comment: It does answer my question but I think it would have been better if you wrote this in more details in the answer section.